# Removing word from panda series of string using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

Suppose I have the following pandas series:

```
x = pd.Series(['box abcd', 'abcd box abcd', 'abcd box', 'abcdboxabcd'])
```

And I want to remove all the occurrences of the word box (note that I don't want to remove all occurrences of the substring box), I have done it like this:

```
x.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([w for w in x.split(' ') if w != 'box']))
```

Which gives me what I expected:

```
0           abcd
1      abcd abcd
2           abcd
3    abcdboxabcd
dtype: object
```

I would like to know if there is a way to do this using regex, for instance:

```
x.str.replace(regex, '')
```

Where regex is the regex matches the word box, I have searched a lot about regex but can't seem to find an answer, is it possible? Or there isn't such regex like that?

Comment: wrap a word boundary: `x.str.replace('\\bbox\\b','')` ?

Comment: `x.str.replace(r'\bbox\b','')`, you're forgetting to make it a raw string literal @anky :)

Comment: @yatu Both gave me the same results, is there a difference between them?

Comment: Yes, without making it a raw string, the backslashes have to be escaped to avoid them being taken as the beginning of an escape @bruno

Comment: Makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `\b` indicating word separation, and then strip extra spaces:

```
x.str.replace(r'\b(\s?box\s?)\b', ' ').str.strip()
```

Output:

```
0           abcd
1      abcd abcd
2           abcd
3    abcdboxabcd
dtype: object
```